# Split Horizon DNS with AWS and Active Directory

Tags: windows, networking, dns, active-directory, amazon-web-services

Is there a way to keep a locally hosted split horizon DNS zone updated with a website and zone hosted in AWS?

Let's call our domain example.com. I have several internally hosted websites and resources that are also available to the internet. Let's say I have a webcam that I make available. If I resolve webcam.example.com internally, I want it to be 192.168.1.1. If I resolve webcam.example.com externally, I want it to be 7.7.7.7. Super easy - I just create the zone in my internal DNS and create the records.

Now the problem. I have a website in Amazon AWS. The IP address of that website seems to change a few times per day. The record in my internally hosted zone is static. So www.example.com might resolve to 5.5.5.5 right now, but later today it might be 6.6.6.6 if I look it up again.

So how do I keep my static internal record up to date with what Amazon may have changed to?

Comment: Could [Route53 Resolver](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-route-53-resolver-for-hybrid-clouds/) help? Could you use a CNAME? You could just let the traffic go over the internet, unless you have a VPN / DirectConnect / another reason for this.

Comment: @Tim I'm pretty new to AWS, so forgive me if I'm misunderstanding anything. I thought using the Route 53 resolver only worked if my clients were in the VPC? Would I have to build a DNS server in the VPC to use as a forwarder from my domain controllers hosting the internal DNS?

Comment: I'm finding your question unclear so it's difficult for me to give much advice. Hybrid cloud DNS can be a complex area, last time I did this I had an engineer looking at it for four weeks to get a viable design, but this was before Route53 resolver was available. I've given you a couple of ideas to follow up. If you can edit your question to be a bit more clear I might find some time to have a think about it later.